# Mac OS : creating a background periodic simple script

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

I have a friend who wants something quite easy : he has a mac, and he would like a very simple script/app that runs in the background. The goal is to replace a file every 5 minutes with one downloaded from the internet.
I would also like a menu on the top bar (like the clock on Mac Os, the wifi, the sound, Dropbox,...)
What would be the easiest way to do that ? Objective C ? AppleScript ? Do you guys have any inspiration for that ?

Thanks a lot

Julien

Comment: Until you said menu bar, the easiest way would be to use `launchd` or a cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be easy with Cocoa, just create an "background" app with the NSMenuExtra (without Dock icon too).

I encourage you to google up some references on how to do this ([e.g. Cocoa Dev Central](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000078.php)).

Sounds like a fun project, best of luck!

Comment: Funny, if I want to accept I get a message : "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes (click on this box to dismiss)"... I'll try in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a Script application, but I don't know if you can get a menubar item that way. Actually, you can do everything except the menubar item in Automator, if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

As far as running in the background goes, I use Lingon to set up the repeating scripts

http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/

Super easy, super reliable.